# Angular Redirect when url has no parameters

Tags: angularjs, url, parameters

When user lost password, an email is sent to his account with an URL. I want the page that controls a reset password only loads if the url has a parameter. Im using Angular.

For example:

if user goes to http://example.com/reset_password/A232Ddade
loads the reset_password/reset_password.html page normally

but

if user goes to http://example.com/reset_password/
redirect to http://example.com/index.html

Another thing to consider is that before rendering the page, I will use the parameter to find the user that will change the password.

To make this happens I have to use some initialize function, read the parameter and if it is present use it or if it is not present redirect to index page? like

```
//At the top of the controller
var init = function () {
   //check if there is query in url
   //and redirect if not 
};
 //and fire it after definition
init();
```

Or Can I use the ui-router module?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems a bit "casual" what you said.... angular is strong with a SPA (single page application), why you don't go with that?

Comment: Because, the url came from an email that users clicks. I not want to be accessed from the menu.

Comment: if you don't put that link in the menu then there's no problems

Comment: and how you avoid someone to write by hand the url? that is why I need to read the parameter and redirect if it is not there

Comment: you can't avoid it if is not single page either, i think that if you use something like `.when('/reset_password/:param', { //...})` it should be ok. If no param is set then the routing is not going anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like standard usage of [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
            when('/reset_password/:param', {templateUrl: 'pageToReset.html',   controller: ResetLogicCtrl}).
            when('/reset_password/', {templateUrl: 'index.html',   controller: IndexCtrl}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **Resolve**, on your route. Take the param and get the user with it, if there is no user, or if param is falsy value, redirect to wherever you want. That way your controller gets the needed data or it redirects.

Comment: but in the case that the param not exists I will call the WS and it has a cost.